Text in arrayformulas won't load unless formatting is changed; when done it shows only on local device
I got a very strange problem in a Google Sheet i'm using for my company. I'll try to explain and since I can't reproduce, I screenrecorded the issue and that record can be found here
The sheet
It's a daily operational sheet that's being used on a store floor to help daily operational management.
The bug
Sometimes we get reports that 'data is not loading', but in fact it IS loaded in the sheet; but only shows up when I change 'formatting' to something random (doesn't matter if i reselect the already selected formatting as in the recording'.
So: '6. Qreader' and '1. Dagplanning Winkelvloer' look empty; but when changing (or reselecting) formatting in 6. Qreader it shows on both tabs.
When I - at a different computer - change the formatting in '6. Qreader', it shows the correct data for me; but all other computers will not show the data. Not even on the same network.
It seems to dissapear the next day.
Datablocks
- 5. Import (O2 = the name of the store)
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("googlespreadsheet";"Extract and pivot table!J:O");"where Col6 ='Store "&O2&"'" ;true)

6. Qreader
Col A: (name)
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(I2:I;SEARCH("(";I2:I)-1));"")
Col B: (shift)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH('5. Import'!E2:E;"^ST");RIGHT('5. Import'!E2:E;LEN('5. Import'!E2:E)-5);'5. Import'!E2:E);))
Col C: (starttime)
=ARRAYFORMULA('5. Import'!C2:C)
Col D: (endtime)
=ARRAYFORMULA('5. Import'!D2:D)
Col E: (total shift)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I);"";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="";"";D2:D-C2:C))))
Col F: (number of 15m breaks)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I);"";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="";"";VLOOKUP(E2:E;'7. Settings'!E6:G12;2;TRUE)))))
Col G: (number of 30m break)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I);"";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="";"";VLOOKUP(E2:E;'7. Settings'!E6:G12;3;TRUE)))))
Col I: (name incl staffnumber)
=ARRAYFORMULA('5. Import'!A2:A)
Col J: (first name only)
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LEFT(I2:I;SEARCH(" ";I2:I)-1);""))

1. Dagplanning Winkelvloer
=IFERROR({QUERY('6. Qreader'!A:G;VLOOKUP(B6;'7. Settings'!O:P;2;0);1);
QUERY('7. Settings'!Y4:AE;;1)};"ERROR: No data available today. Please fill in names on 6. Settings manually.")

Technical facts

The data get's imported from a master data sheet and refreshes every hour (connected to BigQuery), it's found on tab '5. Import'
The data is then extracted to the correct format on the '6. Qreader' tab
Data is then queried in the main tab '1. Dagplanning Winkelvloer'
This full sheet gets deleted every night by a Google Script and then reloaded from a template, so that users can mess with (conditional) formatting or f*ck up cells; but it won't matter because they start with the same template, same formulas and same formatting every single day.

I'm very very very confused and this bug shows up randomly. I can't reproduce it. I need some help.

We tried different formattings
We changed formattings in template
We looked at the arrayformulas, nothing is wrong with them
We checked other stores with the exact same method, nothing weird showing up there
We looked into a patern; but couldn't find any


Welcome to Stack Overflow. File > Settings > Calculation > Iterative calculation often causes weird results like the ones you describe. Turn it off if it is enabled.
